# Why is Mock DbContext empty when initialized in same manner as regular DbContext when running Xunit tests in .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, moq, xunit

So we have an object to keep track of our context for testing and we're looking to Mock the context in order to have it throw an exception a la
ContextMock.Setup(x => x.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny())).ThrowsAsync(new DbUpdateException());

Here is our base context class

```
    public InMemoryZZZContext(string dbName = null)
    {
        _dbName = dbName ?? _dbName;
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DatabaseContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: _dbName)
            .ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.TransactionIgnoredWarning))
            .Options;
       
        TestContext = new ZZZContext(options, UserClaimsServiceMock.Object);
        TestContextMock = new Mock<ZZZContext>(options, UserClaimsServiceMock.Object);
    }
```

In the constructor for the test we have:

```
    public ZZZRepositoryTest()
    {
        Context = new InMemoryZZZContext().TestContext;
        ContextMock = new InMemoryZZZContext().TestContextMock;
        RepositoryMockHelper = new RepositoryMockHelper();
        RepositoryUnderTest = new OrderingArgumentListTypeRepository(Context, RepositoryMockHelper.DependenciesMock.Object);
        RepositoryUnderTestMock = new OrderingArgumentListTypeRepository(ContextMock.Object, RepositoryMockHelper.DependenciesMock.Object);
        // We tried the following on a whim, to no effect
        ContextMock.Setup(x => x.Set<OrderingArgumentListType>()).Returns(new Mock<DbSet<OrderingArgumentListType>>().Object);
    }
```

When we get into the first line of the test, the Context is fully populated, but none of the tables in the ContextMock are populated.

Any ideas as to why the ContextMock might be empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the mock will override any virtual members unless `CallBase` is set to `true`

```
TestContextMock = new Mock<ZZZContext>(options, UserClaimsServiceMock.Object) {
    CallBase = true
};
```

With `CallBase` set to `true`, the members that need to be overridden now need to be explicitly setup for them to behave as expected when exercising the test.

```
ContextMock
    .Setup(x => x.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<MyModel>()))
    .ThrowsAsync(new DbUpdateException());
```

With that the context should invoke base members as expected for those that were not overridden using the setup above, should throw an exception when `SaveChangesAsync` is invoked